# UIViewControllerPreviewing peek not showing my preview

Tags: swift, xcode, 3dtouch

I'm having an issue with the `UIViewControllerPreviewing` API. It was working fine in previous versions of the app (iOS?), but I just noticed that it's not working anymore in current version.

I did not change anything specific to this (just migrated to Swift 4 and this kind of changes), yet this is happening all across the app (not just the example bellow), representing 4-5 *different* force touch peeks and pops.

When I force touch a cell on my collection view, here is what I see. Blurring happens but my previewed view controller doesn't appear.
[image: What I see when force touching]

Note that the pop works fine, my view controller, well configured is pushed onto the navigation stack.

I tried using the UI debugger from Xcode, and it seems that my previewed view controller's view is not given a size, weird.
[image]

Here is my code:

```
extension HomeViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location), let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
            return nil
        }

        // Configure previewing context
        let viewRectInCollectionView = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, from: coverImageView.superview!)
        previewingContext.sourceRect = viewRectInCollectionView

        // Generate cover view
        let viewController = MyViewController(/* some parameters */)

        return viewController
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
    }

}
```

I have also tried to give a preferred content size, but it didn't change anything:

```
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 300.0, height: 300.0)
// or
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 300.0)
```

I would be happy to receive suggestions of things to try, or if you already fixed this issue in your app the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of:

`previewingContext.sourceRect = viewRectInCollectionView`

try:

`previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame`.

I had similar problem when using `collectionView.convert()`.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fix the issue.